# How to find out if GPU supports UEFI?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, uefi, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to run a Windows 10 VM on Ubuntu with GPU passthrough, following [this tutorial](https://www.heiko-sieger.info/running-windows-10-on-linux-using-kvm-with-vga-passthrough/#Tutorial). The tutorial uses UEFI to boot Windows, and states that the GPU needs to support UEFI in order for it to work. It references [this page](https://www.techpowerup.com/vgabios/) to check if my GPU supports UEFI, however my graphics card series is not mentioned there. I was therefore wondering if there are other ways to check if my graphics card supports UEFI?

My graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce MX130 by the way...

Comment: The MX130 has been installed exclusively in UEFI machines so...

Comment: @ChanganAuto make it an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Nvidia Geforce MX130](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/gaming-laptops/nvidia-geforce-mx130/) is a mobile (laptop) graphics chipset released in November 2017. **It has been installed exclusively in UEFI machines**, so you can be sure it supports UEFI.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to take your assurances at face value. =) Still, if possible, it would be nice if you could provide a link to where this is stated specifically.